# Can any one tell me how to make an Image work Like a Button?

Tags: button, android-studio, imageview

I am new in Android , so i want to make an Image View work like a button. So can anyone tell me how to do that?

Thanks In Advance :)

Comment: ImageView has property onClickListener use that interface

Comment: I am trying this    display = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivh3);
    ImageView image1= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivh3);
    image1.OnClickListener(this);                                                                                but it says that cannot resolve onclick listener .. :(

Comment: Have you implemented View.OnClickListener to your class??

Answer (score 1):

Use ImageView's setOnClickListener method e.g. image1.setOnClickListener(this) or you can use ImageButton instead of ImageView.